# input focus is being displayed when only the error layout should be

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I have an input text field for an email.
It has a focus attribute that displays a blue border.
When the email is in a wrong format, the input is in a red border.
However, When there's already a red border i.e. an error in the field and I set focus on the input field, I see the blue border with the red one.
This is the contents of class for the focus:

```
.myClass:focus{
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px #50BADE,inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #50BADE,inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #50BADE,inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

This is the class for the red border:

```
.input.error {
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #DD4B39;
```

}

Is there a way for my to make sure the focus style will not be displayed when the red border is being displayed?

Comment: can you post a demo of what you tried sofar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

If the .error class affects the same property (box-shadow) as focus, it will override it (assuming it has higher or equivalent specificity; use `!important` otherwise). So either make it a red box-shadow or keep your red border while explicitly removing any box-shadow.

Or refine your :focus selector so it doesn't apply to .error: `input:not(.error):focus` (requires CSS3)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I set it to !important and it wroks.